# push update for a specific version of android in the play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the play store that that I am receiving crash reports from and have noticed that there are some crashes that are specific to an android version ( 4.0 - 4.4 ). I want to send out an update to only those android versions. How do I go about doing that because the play store doesn't give me any such option. The minimum api version I am targeting is 16 with a targetSDK version of 27. Do i need to change those values and make a target sdk version of 19 instead and push out the update? If so will it affect the availability of the app to devices with a higher api level?

Comment: Have a look at this might help you https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the Play store with a [Multiple APK configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html).

Suppose the current version of your app has versionCode 100. You produce a new version with versionCode 101, which has:

- minSdkVersion 14 (ICS, version 4.0)
- maxSdkVersion 19 (KitKat, version 4.4)

You then create a release which has both version code 101 and version code 100 in it.

To make things slightly more complicated, you should think about a user who has a KitKat phone and upgrades their Android version. They would then be matched with version 100, but this would be a downgrade from versionCode 101 to versionCode 100, and downgrades are not allowed. So you should also produce a version 102 which is exactly the same as 100.

Because this is so complicated, it might be easier to just deliver the update to everyone, and keep a single APK.